# Punctuation with US measurements

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, writing-style, periods

Should a period be used with a measurement that is a compound term, e.g., ft-lb?

Comment: Periods are commonly not used in measurement contractions at all and adding one (or two) here would look messy.

Comment: What kind of work are you writing— scientific, journalistic, literary? In scholarly and industrial use, periods tend to be omitted altogether, except some style guides prefer *in.* for *inches* to avoid confusion with the word *in*.

Comment: When did Imperial measurements become US measurements?

Comment: I found this interesting bit about the name for US measurements: "There's no official name for the non-metric U.S. system of weights and measures, but the most commonly used terms are:

    “customary system” or “customary units” or “customary weights and measures” (Metric Act, 1866; Mendenhall Order, 1893; NIST SP 345, A Metric America: A Decision Whose Time Has Come, 1971) `http://lamar.colostate.edu/~hillger/faq.html#old-name`

Comment: Perhaps the US inherited them when the empire abandoned them? http://www.mathsisfun.com/metric-imperial-conversion-charts.html

Comment: This is a style issue and will vary.  Technical magazines, for example, will have strict rules on the formatting of measurements (both English and metric) and will usually eschew extraneous periods.  Non-technical magazines will go for a softer style.  But I can't imagine anyone attempting to insert periods into "ft-lb".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - [Imperial units and US units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_and_US_customary_measurement_systems) are apparently both derived from English units. US is not derived from Imperial.

Comment: @Drew OP mentions compound units, and specifically the ft-lb. [This Maplesoft article](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=1447) has: 'Before the International System (SI) of units came into use, there was great scope for errors when solving problems in mechanics. Professor H. Stroud, a physicist and chemist, devised a system for eliminating such errors during the late 1880s while teaching dynamics at Imperial College, London....' There is a link to the mechanics usage. And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) ...

Comment: has: 'The system of imperial units or the imperial system (also known as British Imperial) is the system of units first defined ... in the British Weights and Measures Act of 1824'. I believe OP should attribute correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is, of course, purely a style issue, and I was somewhat surprised at how few style books directly address the OP's question. The best (and only direct) coverage of the question occurs in *Words Into Type*, third edition (1974), still a major reference book in U.S. publishing, despite its age. Here is the relevant entry in *Words Into Type*:

> **Measures, weights, and other units.** Units of measure and weight may be abbreviated in technical copy when they are accompanied by a numeral; never abbreviate units when they follow a spelled-out number. Note that all the following abbreviations are identical in both the singular and the plural and that periods are not usually used (except for *in.*):
>
> [Examples involving multiple-word units of measure:] at wt, atomic weight; bd ft, board foot; bp, boiling point; Btu, British thermal unit; cc, cubic centimeter; cu ft, cubic foot; cps, cycles per second; FM, frequency modulation; **ft-lb, foot-pound**; ...

Although the *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003), doesn't have an extensive list of abbreviations for units of measure as *Words into Type* does, it does touch on the subject of abbreviations for units of measure:

> **9.18** *Abbreviations and symbols.* If an abbreviation or a symbol is used for the unit of measure, the quantity is always expressed by a numeral. [Cross reference omitted.]
>
> [Examples:] 3 mi 55 mph 7 h 3 g 35 mm film

But later *Chicago* thoroughly completely muddies the waters by offering these comments in a subsection on "English Measure":

> **15.71** *Periods.* In the rare instances in which abbreviations for English units of measure are used in scientific copy, they are usually set without periods; in nonscientific contexts, periods are customary.

*Chicago* then goes on (in section 15.73) to endorse such forms as "sq. ft." and "cu. yd." though it doesn't face the ugly music of "ft.-lb."

The *Associated Press Stylebook* (2002), meanwhile, specifies spelling out both dimensions ("Use figures and spell out *inches*, *feet*, *yards*, etc., to indicate depth, height, length and width.") and weights ("Use figures: *The baby weighed 9 pounds, 7 ounces*."), so I doubt that it would approve of *ft-lb* regardless of how you punctuated it.

At the U.S. computer magazines where I've worked, we generally spelled out units of measure except when they appeared in tables, where space was in especially short supply; and in those cases we followed *Words Into Type* in not including periods to punctuate the abbreviations. It makes sense: If your justification for using an abbreviation instead of spelling a word out is that you need to save space, why squander space on periods?

Answer (score 2):

*Units of Weight and Measure, International (Metric) and U.S. Customary*, National Bureau of Standards Miscellaneous Publication 286, May 1967, page 10, says, "No period is used with symbols for units."  The table of units that follows on that same page includes symbols for both SI (metric) and U.S. customary units without trailing periods, making it clear that the rule applies to both types of units of measure.

The responsibility for the setting and maintaining the rules for the use of units of measure within the Federal Government is assigned to the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST), which was the National Bureau of Standards (NBS) prior to 1988.  The Federal Government recommends these rules to the private sector and most style guides follow the lead that NIST/NBS sets for representing units of measure.

This rule is old news--NBS policy on this subject has been consistent since it was first set 80 years ago, in 1936.  *Units of Weight and Measure (U.S. Customary and Metric), Definitions and Tables of Equivalents*, National Bureau of Standards Miscellaneous Publication M121, January 1936, page 6, says, "The period is omitted after all abbreviations of units, except where the abbreviation forms an English word."  As with more recent NBS publications, the table on page 7 in NBS M121 contains both SI (metric) and U.S. customary unit abbreviations without trailing periods (except for "in." for inch), making it clear that the rule applies to both types of units of measure.